# In the angular, how can we check if a value match a pattern?

Tags: regex, angularjs

How can I check if a value match certain pattern in the code?

Not use ng-pattern but in the function.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a directive to do so

Comment: @neda actually just want to have a simple code like what to do in php or JavaScript to check. Any idea?

Comment: use regular expression? you could wrap it into service if you want to reuse it?

Answer (score 10):

Use pure javascript match function.

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var res = str.match(/ain/g);
```

res will be an array with matched values.
You can test if there is match checking array length:

```
if ( res.length > 0 ) 
    console.log("match");
```

from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

Use it in a directive, better as controller since in Angular 2 there would be no controllers.

Answer (score 2):

For HTML, you need to specify the regex in "pattern" object for e.g:

```
<form  name="form1" novalidate ng-submit="data.submitTheForm()">
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here" name="inputName"  ng-model="data.inputName" required="required" pattern="^((?!_)[A-Z a-z0-9])+$" maxlength="20"/></form>
```

Then you need to add the condition in the controller function called on submit

```
 $scope.data.submitTheForm = function() {
 if($scope.form1.projectName.$error.pattern)
                {
                alert("Project name should contain only alphanumeric characters");
                return;
                }
 }
```

Comment: how to show error message or toast in ionic when using pattern in input element ... i added label with red color and when use  *ngIf="patternIpAddress.test(myngmodelname.ipAddress)" but not worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <form name="myform">
        <label class="span5">Full Name:<span style="color: red" ng-show="myform.personname.$error.required" >Must be enter Full name</span>
        </label>

        <input class="span12" type="text" name="personname"  ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="25" required>
        <span style="color: red" ng-show="myform.personname.$error.maxlength">Allow maximum 25 characters.</span>
        <span style="color: red" ng-show="myform.personname.$error.minlength">Allow minimum 2 characters.</span>
    <span style="color: red" ng-show="myform.personname.$error.pattern">Any other symbol are not allow. Only Alphabate allow</span>

    </div>
</form>
```